# Can I set the value of test element's name attribute in dynamic way? not static

Tags: pom.xml, allure, testng.xml

I want to set the value of name element in testng.xml in dynamic way.

See below.

```
<test thread-count="5" name="${browser}">
<parameter name="browser" value="${browser}"/>
```

The command line comes with this option `-Dbrowser=firefox`.

This above testng.xml code works fine in the parameter element but test element.
See the test result in Allure report.

[image]

What I want is to have Allure report displays testname with browser.